# compiling with gradle gives me different values than compiling with eclipse when running getDisplayMetrics() method

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle

I have an odd problem about compilation platforms or pre-processors.

If i compile my android project with eclipse, on runtime `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density` gives me value of .75 (eg.)

If i compile, same method gives me 1.5 (eg.) on the same exact phone.

My project targetSdkVersion (10) and minimumSdkVersion(8) are same. (Actually 2 projects are same)

Any ideas ?

Comment: Surely the binary output of each compilation will be different, but check it anyway.  Once you are sure of this, have a look at gradle docs and your eclipse compiler configuration and try to finetune both in order to produce the same code (target JVM level, debug level, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there will be difference, if the code is compiled with the same android sdk version. I tried printing density. It is giving me the same values in both eclipse(using ant) and gradle generated builds.